# How to rewrite Modelmapper Converter as Lambda Expression (java 1.8)?

Tags: java, spring, lambda, java-8, modelmapper

I use **ModelMapper 2.1.0** and there is an Interface called **Converter**

I'm using this Converter(modelmapper) like this :

```
import org.modelmapper.Converter;

public class MyClass {
    private ModelMaper myMapper = new ModelMapper();      
    Converter<Instant, java.util.Date> myDateConverter;

    @Before 
    public void setup() {
        myDateConverter = new Converter<Instant, java.util.Date>() {

        @Override
        public java.util.Date convert(MappingContext<Instant, java.util.Date> mappingContext) {
                return java.util.Date.from(mappingContext.getSource());
            }
       }
    }

    @Test
    public void fromDto() {
        myMapper.addConverter(myDateConverter);
        ....
        assertThat(domain.getDate()).isEqualTo(dto.getDate())
    }
}
```

Now i just want to rewrite the anonymous inner class with lambda like this :

```
myDateConverter = mappingContext -> java.util.Date.from(mappingContext.getSource());
```

But when I'm testing (JUnit) the converter return `null` when it's the lambda expression.

How to rewrite this anonymous inner class to a lambda expression, which actually really convert?

Comment: Could you post your unit test? It's really not possible that null is returned, if anything it shouldn't compile at all.

Comment: to achieve this you need to have a functional interface for this lambda expression but the converter what you used is not a functional interface

Comment: i changed the class to test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this problem is that ModelMapper can't resolve generic types from lambda expression correctly.

Here is the workaround:

```
modelMapper.typeMap(Source.class, Destination.class)
  .setConverter(ctx -> new Destination(ctx.getSource));
```

Answer (score 2):

The lambda itself is valid and should work. The restriction is that `Converter` must be a functional interface, not the class.

> The target type of this expression must be a functional interface

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Converter<T1, T2> {
    public Date convert(MappingContext<Instant, Date> mappingContext);
}
```

Then the lambda looks the same and should work:

```
myDateConverter = mappingContext -> java.util.Date.from(mappingContext.getSource());
```

Comment: by default, org.springframework.core.convert.Converter is a functional interface right ?

Comment: I though it's OP's custom class. Yes, `org.springframework.core.convert.Converter` is a functional interface. Then the lambda should work.

Comment: I think the problem is that we can't resolve the generic types of a converter very well.

Comment: maybe you can try
modelMapper.typeMap(Source.class, Destination.class).setConverter(ctx -> new Destination(ctx.getSource));

or
modelMapper.addConverter(Source.class, Destination.class, ctx -> new Destination(ctx.getSource));

Comment: @AshokKumarN i'm using the converter from org.modelmapper.Converter itself. Its not a custom one.

Comment: @ChunHanHsiao modelMapper.typeMap(Source.class, Destination.class).setConverter(ctx -> new Destination(ctx.getSource)); it's working. Can you add it as Answer?

Comment: if you use this org.springframework.core.convert.Converter this code will work as said by @Nikolas